# Umbraco ApplicationStarted not getting called after upgrading to version 7.4.3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, umbraco

I have a website that worked fine on Umbraco 7.2

I updated it to 7.4.3 using nuget and after that my ApplicationStarted method is not getting called.

The class looks like this

```
    public class AppEventHandler : ApplicationEventHandler
    {
        private static readonly Logger _log = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

        protected override void ApplicationStarted(UmbracoApplicationBase umbracoApplication,
            ApplicationContext applicationContext)
        {
           //startup code here.....
        }
    }
```

The `LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();`line gets hit but the ApplicationStarted is never called.

And it works fine if I downgrade back to the previous version.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Fixed it by implementing `IApplicationEventHandler` interface instead of subclassing abstract `ApplicationEventHandler` class.

```
public class BootStrapper : IApplicationEventHandler
{
    public void OnApplicationInitialized(UmbracoApplicationBase umbracoApplication, ApplicationContext applicationContext)
    {
        //....
    }

    public void OnApplicationStarted(UmbracoApplicationBase umbracoApplication, ApplicationContext applicationContext)
    {
        //....
    }

    public void OnApplicationStarting(UmbracoApplicationBase umbracoApplication, ApplicationContext applicationContext)
    {
        //....
    }
}
```